# Adjust paragraph spacing in OneNote?

Tags: onenote

Is there a way to adjust the paragraph spacing in OneNote either on the phone or online/OneDrive? My to do lists and notes are a bit spread out and I'd like them tighter.

All the help online points to the ribbon option in the **full product**. I don't currently have access to that.

Comment: Doesn't currently seem to be possible with either the mobile or online versions of OneNote.

Comment: Why don't you have access to the full product?

Comment: Styles clear formatting worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out how to remove paragraph spacing in OneNote Online:

- Select the text you want to re-format.
- Click the HOME tab at the top.
- Click the down arrow in STYLES.
- At the bottom of the list, click CLEAR FORMATTING.

All styles except NORMAL also remove the spacing. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to adjust spacing outside the stock list of styles.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, adjustable paragraph or line spacing is possible only in the Windows desktop version of OneNote. It doesn't seem possible in OneNote for Mac, MX for Windows 8/8.1/10, Online, iOS, or Android. It may be possible in OneNote for Windows 10 for phones, but I highly doubt it.

Whenever I copy text from the web into OneNote Online, the text has somewhat larger paragraph spacing but not line spacing.